# Why the class not active when click on the tab?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I retrieve the data from database and want to display it as bootstrap tab, but when I click on the tab the detail did not show out.

The code

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#2363delTG" aria-expanded="false">2363delTG</a>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#3838T>C" aria-expanded="true">3838T>C</a> 
  </li>
</ul>

<div id="2363delTG" class="tab-pane fade active in"></div>
<div id="3838T>C" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
```

I click on href=#2363delTG, the detail show and the class is active in, but when I click href=#3838>C, the detail not show and the class is not active.

Comment: add jquery code..

Comment: `3838>C` is class? `>` is exiting the tag itself

Comment: Hi jenell. In this part `<div id="3838T>C" class="tab-pane fade"></div>`, try to avoid characters that is not alphanumerical (e.g `>`).

Comment: I don't see any code that would make anything active (except the hard coded class `active`). Please include _all_ relevant code in your question. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @jenell, Kindly go through below links  1) https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/panels-with-nav-tabs 2) https://codepen.io/wizly/pen/BlKxo

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `>` in class name `3838T>C` change it to `3838TC`.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" href="#2363delTG" aria-expanded="false">2363delTG</a></li>
 <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#3838TC" aria-expanded="true">3838TC</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="2363delTG" class="tab-pane fade active in"></div>
<div id="3838TC" class="tab-pane fade"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for the advice. I changed it and now its work!